# Need to change the width of Vuetify notify or remove close button

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, notify

I'm using Vuetify notify for notifications. I'm unable to change the width of the notification banner. I need either to change the width or remove the close icon from the banner. Alternatively, is there any other easy notification method?

#### main.js:

```
import VuetifyNotify from 'vuetify-notify';

Vue.use(notify, {
  vuetify,
  options: {
    toast: {
      x: "right",
      y: "top",
      color: "green"
    }
  }
});
```

In my Vue component:

```
this.$notify.toast("Hello toast");
```

Comment: Its for dialog, not for toast notification

Answer (score 0):

Based on [documentation](https://github.com/canhkieu/vuetify-notify), you may use dialog setting to configure the width.

sample:

```
Vue.use(notify, {
  vuetify,
  options: {
    toast: {
      x: "right",
      y: "top",
      color: "green"
    },
    dialog: {
      width: 400 //here
    }
  }
});
```